# Improve asyncio.sleep(wait) performance for small wait values (< 10ms)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-asyncio

I'm using a Raspi to control a stepper motor via a `python-osc` server, producing trigger signals in an async process via the `await asyncio.sleep(wait_in_s)`.

I found out that the non-blocking `asyncio.sleep` routine shows very poor performance at frequencys above 100Hz in comparesion to the blocking `time.sleep()` function, as it produces discrete steps.

`Asyncio.sleep()`: Commanded vs. measured sleep time:

[image: Asyncio.sleep(): Commanded vs. measured sleep time]

`time.sleep()`:  Commanded vs. measured sleep time:

[image: time.sleep(): Commanded vs. measured sleep time]

Is there a possibility to use other async co-routines with better performance, or using the `time.sleep()` function in an asynchronous way?

I cannot use a hardware pwm controller as I have to count the pulses to stop the stepper motor at a specific angle, and ramping up/down the velocity.

Testbench for the asyncio.sleep():

```
import time
import asyncio
import numpy as np

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

async def main(frequency):
    time_last = time.time()
    x_end = 3
    sleep_meas = 0
    await asyncio.sleep(1 / (frequency))
    await asyncio.sleep(1 / (frequency))
    await asyncio.sleep(1 / (frequency))
    sleep_meas = time.time() - time_last
    print(f"{frequency}: {1/(sleep_meas/x_end)}")
    return 1/(sleep_meas/x_end)

f = np.geomspace(10, 5000, 1000)

f_meas = []
for freq in f:
    f_meas.append(asyncio.run(main(freq)))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(f, f_meas)
ax.set_xlabel("commanded frequency")
ax.set_ylabel("measured frequency")

plt.savefig("test3.png")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your test program only has one Task, therefore the performance you observe is a "best-case" result.  As soon as you add other Tasks the situation will become worse, perhaps much worse, as each asyncio await expression allows the event loop to cycle between all the other tasks.  This approach is not going to work very well.  I think you should consider using some dedicated hardware for stepper motor control, for example an Arduino.  Using a high level OS and a high-level language, which supports many types of concurrency, makes it difficult to get precise timing control.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of `asyncio` features have higher overhead than native system calls like `sleep()`. This is because `asyncio` is largely implemented in pure Python.

`asyncio` really shines when multiplexing large numbers of network calls on a single thread. In other words, it's designed around high *networking* concurrency.

Consider using `sleep()` calls in a dedicated thread, rather than using `asyncio.sleep()`.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the `asyncio.sleep()` is designed for cooperative multitasking and it doesn't guarantee accurate timing.

BTW, a couple of years ago, I almost had the same issue with the Orange Pi board and the `asyncio`. At that time, I used the following technique — checking the time repeatedly until the desired interval has passed. Also, it's worth noting that, Python's time module provides a `time.perf_counter()` function, which offers the highest available resolution timer on your system.

Your code would be something like:

```py
import time
import asyncio

async def accurate_sleep(wait_time):
    start = time.perf_counter()
    while True:
        if (time.perf_counter() - start) >= wait_time:
            break
        await asyncio.sleep(0)

async def main(frequency):
    time_last = time.perf_counter()
    x_end = 3
    await accurate_sleep(1 / frequency)
    await accurate_sleep(1 / frequency)
    await accurate_sleep(1 / frequency)
    sleep_meas = time.perf_counter() - time_last
    print(f"{frequency}: {1/(sleep_meas/x_end)}")
    return 1/(sleep_meas/x_end)
```

Plot:

[image]

However, the main issue with the above code is that one of your CPU cores would be full load due to the very fast time checker!

---

Alternatively, another approach that you can adopt is using a thread or process doing a normal `time.sleep()` within your async methods as follows:

```py
import time
import asyncio

from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def blocking_sleep(wait_time):
    time.sleep(wait_time)

async def run_in_executor(executor, wait_time):
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    await loop.run_in_executor(executor, blocking_sleep, wait_time)

async def main(frequency):
    time_last = time.time()
    x_end = 3
    sleep_meas = 0

    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        await run_in_executor(executor, 1 / frequency)
        await run_in_executor(executor, 1 / frequency)
        await run_in_executor(executor, 1 / frequency)

    sleep_meas = time.time() - time_last
    print(f"{frequency}: {1/(sleep_meas/x_end)}")
    return 1/(sleep_meas/x_end)
```

Plot:

[image]

---

Ultimately, [Asyncer](https://asyncer.tiangolo.com/) is a package released newly to make async stuff simpler. It has a feature called [`asyncify`](https://asyncer.tiangolo.com/tutorial/asyncify/) that you can call a sync method in an async way. In fact, it should use thread under the hood like the above code. That's why I decided to test it here for the first time as well:

```py
import time

from asyncer import asyncify

def blocking_sleep(wait_time):
    time.sleep(wait_time)

async def main(frequency):
    time_last = time.time()
    x_end = 3
    sleep_meas = 0
    await asyncify(blocking_sleep)(wait_time=1 / frequency)
    await asyncify(blocking_sleep)(wait_time=1 / frequency)
    await asyncify(blocking_sleep)(wait_time=1 / frequency)
    sleep_meas = time.time() - time_last
    print(f"{frequency}: {1/(sleep_meas/x_end)}")
    return 1/(sleep_meas/x_end)
```

Plot:

[image]

However, the result was not as expected!

Comment: Unfortunately, running a blocking `sleep()` on an executor using `asyncio.run_in-executor()` or `asyncify` adds quite a bit of overhead to the sleep call, which is probably why the results are not as expected!

Your first approach, using `asyncio.sleep(0)` shows a promising resolution, but as expected locks up a whole CPU, which probably won't cut it on a RPi.

An excellent in-depth look at a couple of approaches though!

Comment: Locking up a whole CPU to achieve sub-millisecond timing control seems to me a necessity.  If the CPU running your program is doing other things, I don't see how your program can reliably get control of the hardware at precisely the right moments to drive a stepper motor.  Do you know how fast the RPi will switch between processes?  I wouldn't expect it to be sub-millisecond (which is what the OP seems to want).

Answer (score -1):

`time.sleep` isn't async, so it's useless to you.

The best suggestion I've got is that `asyncio.sleep(0)` doesn't actually sleep, it just queues you up at the end of the line in the queue, so if you compute when you want to be done with the wait, and just loop with `asyncio.sleep(0)` until you've hit that time, that's the lowest latency you can possibly get that still uses async features. If that doesn't work, it likely implies that your other tasks are monopolizing the event loop, rather than it being an inherent problem with `asyncio.sleep`'s latency.

As a side-note, you don't want to use `time.time` for measuring durations; `time.monotonic` will give the same results, and avoid the risk of a clock correction/change messing with measurements.

Comment: This is likely going to generate a lot of CPU churn, particularly on a low-powered device like a RPi.

Comment: @Dave: If they're trying for a level of sleep granularity greater than `asyncio.sleep` can provide, they don't have a lot of options that remain purely async.

Comment: That's my point! :) The approach taken by my answer is that you should run these high-resolution `sleep()` calls on a dedicated thread.